# What does this kind of variable mean in Android ? (URL... urls,Integer... progress)

Tags: java, android, variables

From here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> doInBackground(URL... urls)
>
> onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)

Are they a set of URL type named urls and a set of Integer type named progress ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Android specific, it's [Java varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Simply speaking they are like `URL[]` and `Integer[]`

Answer (score 2):

They are called `Varargs`.. they are kind of Arrays you can say but not exactly Arrays.. They hold multiple values of respective types(in your case URL and Integer ).. and you can access them just like Arrays using index..., like `urls[0]`.. etc.. and while calling those methods just pass multiple arguments with comma separator..